Is there a way to get more than a 0.5 V spread in a 5 V circuit with only a 100 ohm variable resistor?
The FSR I want to use in a circuit only has a usable range between 2-300 ohms, used in a voltage divider circuit with another 200 ohm resistor I get between 2.5 - 3 V out (0.5 V spread).  I would like to increase the spread, say between 2-4 V.  Is there a way to do this?


Do you feel comfortable using an opamp? Where is this signal going?

When you write "2-300 ohms" is it safe to assume you actually mean "200 to 300 ohms", rather than "2 ohms to 300 ohms"?

What is an FSR? (I'm only doing electronics for 50 years and haven't come across the term yet.)

@Transistor - Hi, FSR = Force Sensitive Resistor (sometimes called a Force Sensing Resistor). Here's an Adafruit overview. || FYI this OP has asked previous questions about circuits using them.

If you are getting 2.5 V to 3.0 V out of the divider with it only loaded by a high-impedance voltmeter then the range of the potentiometer is 200 to 300 ohms. At 2.5 V out you have half the supply voltage so the resistances must be equal. At 3.0 V you have 3/5 of the supply voltage, so the pot’s resistance must be 300 ohms.
Use the voltage divider formula to find the range of resistance you’ll need.

Here's how you want to do it:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R6 is optional but will add stability near the transition. 47k - 100k would be a good place to start.

Thanks much for the replies, I was hoping there might be a way to do what I want without an amplifier of some sort. The FST (force sensitive resistor) only gives a range of 200-300 ohms when measuring the force I want to use in my circuit. The 2.5-3v goes to a dual comparator (TLV1702) with the 2.5v (2-3v) line trimmed with a 1k pot, problem is at 3v both high and low end are equal and the circuit stops working.

@JimKailey Did you try trimming the comparator(s) reference signal instead of the FSR? Based on this new information, it sounds like what you want is much simpler than what I'm presenting - I falsely assumed you wanted to use most of the range of an ADC input. Which would be the case 95% of the time. Are you using 1 or 2 (window) comparators?

@JimKailey OK, what you are requesting is much different than what you want - you say "I want to extend the range of the sensor signal". What you mean "I want to activate a buzzer when my FSR exceeds a limit". The treatment is totally different and invalidates my answer. I will update to reflect the new information (that should be presented in the question body).

I've added the complete circuit to my original question, sorry for such a rough diagram. As mentioned, when the 1K trimmer pot is adjusted to 1 K the lower input line to the comparator also inputs 3 V and it stops working. I'm a relative newby and played around with different value resistors in a voltage divider calculator and couldn't come up with any combination to open up the 0.5 V input voltage.

@JimKailey - Unfortunately you have made a big mistake in changing the question after answers have been written. Even if this site member is willing to change their whole answer after that change, such a change still makes the other answers appear wrong/incomplete. That is why changing a question is not allowed. Therefore I have reversed your change to the question. || Instead please use the answers you got to the original question and upvote/áccept as you choose. || If those answers here are not enough and if you believe you have a different question, then ask it as a new question. TY

@JimKailey - Also, the schematic you added (now removed) is not all your own work. To avoid plagiarism, you are required to comply with the site rule on referencing when you post copied/adapted material from elsewhere onto Stack Exchange. || Looking back at your first question, you first added the copied schematic there. Although the comments were deleted after becoming obsolete, I explained the referencing requirement, you added the missing reference and I then improved it. It is still required to reference the original source even after minor changes to it.

@MOSFET - I appreciate you trying to help, but we're not going to allow this question to be changed, which invalidates the other answers given to the original question. || I have encouraged the OP to ask a new question, instead of trying to change this one, if they have a different question.

@SamGibson Understandable. Jim just doesn't know how the site works.

Here is a simple way with an inexpensive op-amp. The left schematic is the rheostat at minimum (200Ω total) the right with the rheostat at maximum (300Ω total).
You can change the three resistors around the op-amp (R1, R2, R3) over a wide range provided you maintain the ratios. The values shown happen to be standard E96 values for 1% resistors.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Yeah. This is the better answer.
